# Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ms-access, oledbconnection

Why **Microsoft Access Database Engine 2016 Redistributable is not working** using the connection string

```
*string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + sourceFile + ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb,
*.accdb)};DBQ=path to mdb/accdb file;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1\"";*
```

It throws an error

> "The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the
> local machine."

and after installing `"2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components"`
it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your application is running in 32 bit mode and you installed 64 bit driver